# Text in PDF render of Reporting Services report "overprints"

Tags: sql-server, pdf, reporting-services

A report I have been working on some time ago started mis-rendering around Christmas. Some of the text boxes on it suddenly started rendering each character in their text content on top of each other, as if the printing of each character no longer "advances the cursor" to the correct position for the next one. The report is rendered to PDF by URL access.

Anyone seen this behavior before?
Any idea what could be causing this?
I'm just curious, actually.

(I currently have no idea what was changed on the server "around Christmas".)

Answer (score 6):

I've ran in to this once before. My problem was two textboxes were overlapping by barely a pixel. This kept them from "pushing" each other so the text didn't overwrite the other. 
So make sure your textbox objects aren't touching, hopefully that is it, easy fix, otherwise I wish you luck.

Comment: I haven't seen the PDF issue but if you do have overlapping text boxes you will get warned when you deploy from BIDS to the Server.  It gives the object name that is offending so you can track it in the Designer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with text overlapping and rendering weird when printing and exporting to pdf of an ssrs report.

As Dustin says, the problem is that textboxes were overlapping.

[image: overlapping text]

Comment: This looks different than the problem that was reported to me (prompting my original question). Am almost certain no textboxes were overlapping, but within one Textbox all the characters that made up its contents where overlapping, as if all individually rendered left-aligned in the box.